# Winter Bash Issues

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2018

I click the Winter Bash icon and it seems to hang with the ellipses on loop.

[image]

I also try changing my hat (when it does work) and it pops up with the error (similar to)

> An error occurred while trying to change hat

[image]

Then when I hit save again it says (again, similar to),

> Can only change hat every 10s

This happening to anyone else?

**Edit:** Ok I just tried again - worked instantly? *Pos* network hang? Pos quick git pull on production? xD

**Edit2:** forgot to mention I was on Firefox 64.0 on Linux Mint 19.

**Edit3:** Seems to be ok for me but seems it's still intermittent for others (based on related list alone)

**Edit4:** Tested changing hats now - seems all OK. Tested both changing hat without tweaking using controls and tested changing hat after tweaking with controls - both seem OK. However, on a normal page, F12 console shows:

> ReferenceError: winterBashCurrentHats7611062 is not defined current-hats:1:1
>   
>   https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/api/current-hats:1:1

Comment: yes, the same for me ... cannot wear hats :/

Comment: @TemaniAfif good to know it's not just me :) do you get the long load times too?

Comment: not too long, probably 2/3s

Comment: @TemaniAfif hmm.. maybe just my dodgy internet then xD

Comment: I experienced that. Some of the XHR responses I got back were "400" with a JSON object only telling something similar to `{"error": "could not wear the hat"}`. I just kept trying until it worked. :shrug:

Comment: @E_net4iskindandwelcoming did it ever work? Or is it still an ongoing battle?

Comment: @E_net4iskindandwelcoming nvm checked your prof. xD

Comment: @treyBake Just do it like Robocop. Keep punching it until it works.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I see you have hat.

Comment: @Sinatr After trying a dozen of times ...

Comment: I am noticing general sluggishness with the asynchronous interface such as posting a comment, editing one, or viewing more comments on a post.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Even up-voting a comment takes a couple of seconds...

Comment: @Adinia Confirmed. It seems like everything from Inbox to comment upvoting to profile page tabs is affected and everything in between. Somebody done goofed in a commit somewhere.

Comment: I'd add another bug, it is 6 months early (or late) for my half of the world :)

Comment: FWIW, I've been trying on and off since yesterday, and I keep getting that error.

Comment: @deceze hmm, I thought it had resolved *itself* - what browser are you using? pos related??

Comment: Safari, also tried in Chrome. I rather suspect geographic issues, my local CDN proxy or whatever fails…?

Comment: @deceze there may be your problem right there ;) haha kidding aside, I'll do some console'ing and see what happens, pushing `F12 ` now - in console already has `ReferenceError: winterBashCurrentHats7611062 is not defined` error

Comment: @GuillermoVasconcelos me too but it was only 15C here today so at least the weather is trying to get into the Winter Bash spirit!

Comment: @Nick don't rub it in, it was -3 this morning xD

Comment: @treyBake we just had some friends from the UK visit and even they complained about the weather!

Comment: @Nick it would be un-british to not complain ;) haha

Comment: Hmm, a two year old bug resurfaces. I get the error occurred while changing hat multiple times, finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

Bumpidy-bump. This is still *not* working for me. Any hat, any browser, anytime.

I suppose it has something to do with me not being able to [login](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/auth/login) at http://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com:

[image: Oops! Something Bad Happened!]

Comment: In fact, yes, I did happen to reboot my machine, clear caches, disable content blockers… And *this is* my support hotline… :o)

Comment: Mac OS Mojave, Safari browser, also tried Chrome.

Comment: I don't expect *you* to be able to solve this, thanks for the attempt though. This just needs to be brought to the attention of the right person at the mothership.

Comment: Winter Bash is over :( did you ever have the pleasure of wearing a hat? Or did it stay bugged?

Comment: Nope, ‘t was a hatless bash this year. Totally anecdotally speaking, I think I saw way fewer hats this year, so I can’t be the only one…!?

Comment: Hm that sucks, sorry to hear :'( I'm sure they'll do a feedback meta post/poll thing where peeps can raise more awareness around the bugs