# Is the entire network's performance affected by this year's Winter Bash?

Tags: support, bug, performance

Is it just me, or has the entire network bogged down since the introduction of this year's Winter Bash?

I noticed that the questions thread, comments, answers etc. take quite a bit more time to load lately ever since the Winter Bash started.

I haven't seen anything posted here about it.

Every other websites I frequently use load well, Google etc.

This is only happening (to me) while on the Stack / meta network.

Comment: It's not just you. I assume it's due to Winter Bash but it could be a coincidence.

Comment: @Stijn Ok. Well, some seem to disagree with me. No worries. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: We had some issues earlier which we resolved, but we are noticing some other slowness and are investigating it.

Comment: @Taryn Ok, thanks. I was going to edit my question by asking if this happens at each year's Winter Bash. I can't remember if this was the case for years passed.

Comment: Almost an hour later, still feels like it's sluggish. :(

Comment: We've been Winter Bashed

Comment: @j08691 *lol!* - Heh, good one. That we were :-))

Comment: RE: " I was going to edit my question" I don't recall this being an issue in previous years. I do remember one April fool's was particularly problematic though

Comment: @MartinSmith was the tamagotchi thing an April fools feature? Those websockets, though...

Comment: That's the one. [StackEgg](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289032/73226)

Comment: may be the website started freezing in winter

Comment: @user13267 *lol!* good one!

Comment: if everyone stopped wearing hats the problem would be solved.

Comment: Related [Winter Bash Issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377742)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I _hat_ you for even thinking to put away the hats.

Comment: no no :) I meant that like "If everyone stopped breathing the problem would be solved". Hats are life

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Or we could get all of the Infinity Stones and snap the fingers! Will solve half the problems at least ;-)

Comment: well, I have more hats than stones. I'll stick with those.